# Filtering by value parameter

Tags: powerbi

We're embedding PowerBI reports in a web page, and setting filters from our own code.

Main fact table is `Event`, which has a `Date` and a `Duration` (in milliseconds).

Desired output is something like

```
Date        # of events  % Standard
01/02/2022       34          95%    ...
01/03/2022      193         100%    ...
...
```

`% Standard` means "percentage of these events that have a duration less than a value". Now, I can certainly `CALCULATE`, `SUM` and `FILTER` my way to doing so, except...

That value is input from the user. It'll change from run to run. The user can put in 1ms, 55ms, 123456ms. How do I get that arbitrary value from the UI to somewhere I can get at it in the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished this by creating a tally table (just a single field, 1-1,000,000), which is filtered to the desired value by the UI. The DAX formula then just picks up the value.